# redefinition of ‘main’

Tags: c

As I am new to programming, I was trying to write a simple code using functions which will give me the addition of three numbers. Here's the code!

```
/* Your includes go here */
#include <stdio.h>

int addThreeNumbers(int a, int b, int c)
{ 
    int d;
    d = a + b + c;
    return(d);

    /* Complete this function only
       DO NOT write main function. 
    */
}

int main()
{
    int x, y, z, sum;
    printf("Enter the three numbers: ");
    scanf(" %d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    sum = addThreeNumbers(x, y, z);
    printf("The sum is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

And the error was as follows:

```
solution.c:30:5: error: redefinition of ‘main’
solution.c:15:9: note: previous definition of ‘main’ was here
```

Comment: Probably you have more than one source in your project containing `main`.

Comment: i dont see anything wrong here.Is this your full code >

Comment: there's no line 30 in the code you pasted

Comment: And the comment says "    /* Complete this function only
       DO NOT write main function. 
   */" Probably for a reason.

Comment: Is this your complete code or it is just a part of it since this one part if compiled separately would be compile and run as properly.

Comment: you must be having two `main function` in one `.c file`. You have not mentioned code at line number 30. As above code works fine.

Comment: It looks like a part of some skeleton project for some homework. There is a `main` elsewhere in the project tree.

Answer (score 1):

You have another main function in the code somewhere. Post the complete code and I will take a closer look. But that is the only way you can receive this error

Answer (score 0):

In modern C, empty argument parentheses mean that the type and number of arguments is unknown.

Although this segment runs fine with most compilers, yours might be picky. Try declaring main with zero arguments explicitly, like this:

```c
int main(void) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: I afraid it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is one of the online coding sites' question. They put in the main function themselves by appending it to the code, you don't have to explicitly write it. Delete the main function you have written and check if that works out.

Comment: Yes! It is an online coding sites' question.

Comment: Just delete the main function in your code and submit it. It should work